# scheduled interactive script does not open its window

Tags: powershell, interactive, windows-task-scheduler

I have a powershell script (that runs a batch program) that works when running in a powershell window or when executed via explorer to "run with powershell". But when I try to make it run from Windows Scheduler, it does not open the window for the batch program and just idles (as seen in task manager). My scheduler command is: `PowerShell.exe C:\....\myscript.ps1`
The command (inside the ps script) to run the batch file is: `Start-Process c:\BATS\....\mybatch.bat -Wait`.
It is set to run daily, but only when I am logged on. My understanding of `-Wait` is to make PS wait until the batch process finishes.

Comment: The Window Scheduler you need to specify the User Account to use.  When you do not specify the User Account the System Account is used and there is no Environment so the PATH variable and the PSMODULEPATH is not defined.

Comment: Using your suggestion, the script runs, however, that script, in turn does a start-process for a batch file and now I have a dilemma (not sure if I should start a new question). The batch file interacts with the user, then uses Windows START command to initiate a Window that waits for interaction from another window (this works as designed). The batch file does not wait after initiating this program, but the Macrium Script never regains control.

Comment: Check Event Viewer for errors when script runs.  A service has an option for delay start when starting automatically when PC is turned on.

Comment: 1


It appears that I needed to:

1. insert $proc= in front of the Start-Process call and
2. replace -Wait with -PassThru
3. insert $proc.WaitForExit() after the Start-Process call.